# What is the story of Krishna as DWARAKANATH?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, dwarakanath

What is the story behind  DWARAKANATH ? Is that a particular form of Krishna or just a different representation?

[image]

Comment: Where is this temple located?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBtnDGK7kUo

Comment: https://temple.dinamalar.com/en/new_en.php?id=1015

Comment: https://www.gujaratexpert.com/dwarka-history/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jBUsYV82wg